# Ideal HTML table manipulation solution

Tags: html, sorting, pagination, html-table, filtering

I am building an HTML table based on the results of a query that returns XML that I'm converting to an HTML table using XSL.  I've been asked to add sorting, pagination and filtering.  I was able to add some javascript libraries to enable sorting and pagination, and a different library to enable the filtering.  However, since they are separate libraries, they do not cooperate, so when I filter, the table doesn't keep to the constraints of the 'entries per page' field.

I made some attempts at a few jQuery solutions, but couldn't get them to work.  What I'm looking for is the best and (naturally) the easiest solution to adding pagination, column sorting and column filtering without the need to press enter or hit any buttons.

Comment: where do execute XSL transformations?

Comment: That's not important. From my post:  What I'm looking for is the best and (naturally) the easiest solution to adding pagination, column sorting and column filtering without the need to press enter or hit any buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.datatables.net/
Table Widget seems to be able to do the js part. 
Looks complicated too

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tableId').dataTable();
} );
```

Comment: I tried using this but wasn't able to get it to work.  Have you had any luck with it?

Comment: Can you tell me if I'm doing something wrong?  I've added the references to js files as follows:   <script src="Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"/>
                    <script src="Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
                    <script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"/>  and am kicking it off using this: $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').dataTable();
} );     but I keep getting this error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

Comment: sorry for delay. adding dataTables and dataTables.min looks like overkill. also i added jquery before dataTables